# i am trying to get otp from mysql database try to send in password but how to send that otp in using java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
enter code here:
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InterruptedException
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\selenium setup\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver d= new ChromeDriver();
    
    d.manage().window().maximize();
    
    d.get("https://app.canarytext.com/login");
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-input/input")).sendKeys("7722033278");
    
    d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-button")).click();
    
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         System.out.println("Driver loaded");          
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://52.165.37.155:3306/reviews?useSSL=false","canarysql@admin","Uhg@8d64!");

         System.out.println("Connected to MySQL DB");
            
              Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select *  from users WHERE  username = 7722033278;");

                while (rs.next())
                {                                       
                            String OTP = rs.getString(4);                                                  
                            System. out.println(" "+OTP);   
                 d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-input[2]/input")).sendKeys("+OTP+");  
                    }       
                 // closing DB Connection       
                con.close();    
                
                d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-button")).click();
                System.out.println("login successfully");
        }
             
    }
```

Output :

Driver loaded
Connected to MySQL DB
158445
login successfully

i want to enter otp (158445) in this line (d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-input[2]/input")).sendKeys("+OTP+");  )

please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT " " the OTP!

```java
d.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/app-root/ion-app/ion-router-outlet/app-login/div/div/div/form/ion-input[2]/input")).sendKeys(OTP);
```

Comment: thanks @peter ...did the changes: sendKeys(String.valueOf(OTP)); it worked for me.

Comment: Hi, @Priyasude , please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) , it will help others and myself :)